# Visual Studio - launch .bat file as startup project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

I have a C++ program I'm trying to debug. I normally run this from a .bat file which does some file cleanup before running the program. I can run my program from this script and attach the debugger, but it would be more convenient to launch the .bat file from VS. If I set the startup project's Command property to the bat file I get an error that it's an unrecognized binary format (because it's not a binary format, I suppose). I can set the command to cmd.exe and a command shell opens, but I haven't figured out how to pass the .bat file to the command shell. I've tried including it on the properties Command line, with and without a redirection char (<), and tried passing it as the argument to the command, but neither of these work. I've gotten close enough that I think there must be a way to do this, but I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: I could do that, but I would prefer to automate the step to make debugging cycles easier. In addition, there are cases when the script is more complicated. Again, I could just run the part of the script that comes before my program call, but that means switching from VS, running the script, then switching back. Not the end of the world (it's what I'm doing now), but I'm hoping there's a nice integrated solution.

Answer (score 2):

Some visual studios have this option, some don't. I'll post both cases

### If your VS has this option

- Right click the "project", and go to properties -> debug

  - In "Start Action" select "start external program", and put `c:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`
  - In start options, put command line arguments: `/c your_bat.bat`
  - Set a working directory if necessary

Save and happy debugging

### If your VS doesn't have this option

When you do the above, a `your_project.csproj.user` file is created/updated in the same directory as `your_project.csproj`, with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectView>ShowAllFiles</ProjectView>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <StartProgram>C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe</StartProgram>
    <StartWorkingDirectory>c:\your_working_directory\</StartWorkingDirectory>
    <StartArguments>/c your_bat.bat</StartArguments>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Create or update this file including the above. Careful not to remove other things (if there is any). You can also expand this to other configurations by replicating the `PropertyGroup` with different configurations like `'Release|AnyCPU'` and other configurations that your project might have. (This is possible in some versions of VS via interface)

**Warning:** you need to reload your project in Visual Studio for this change to take effect. (Right click on the project, unload - then again, load)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that instead of calling the batch file that is at the end is starting your application, you add a post-build event in your "Build Events" project settings. In the post-Build event type your clean-up code, but omit the "program start" line. Let VS run your program. This way you do not need to attach to the program

Comment: The problem with using a post build event is that you then need to do a build each time you run. If I'm just running debug cycles, setting different breakpoints, pondering the results, etc, then I don't necessarily need to do a build between runs.

Comment: Good point. Have you tried "Custom Build Step"? There you can specify the commands and select when to execute it. If you select "Execute Before" run, then I guess it will execute it even if no build have been done

Comment: I tried a custom build step, using Execute Before Run, and listing the .bat file (fully specified path) as the Command Line, but it doesn't appear to run. I get no error on the custom build step, but the effect of running the .bat file is not appearing, so I assume it's not being run. I also tried Execute Before Prepare to Run, same thing. Also tried "call foo.bat", same thing. tried cmd.exe, same thing.   Even if I can get this to run, there's still a problem. The project is part of a large solution which is built by cmake. Cmake wipes out the custom build.